# How to save a nested object in react js form input using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios, react-hooks

Here I am trying to save category_id to database which is part of category object like
object:{
category_id:""
}
But doing the following way is throwing error "detatched entity passed to persist".It's confusing.Please helo

```
            <FormGroup>
                <label for="category_id">category_id</label>
                <Input
                    placeholder="Enter category id"
                    id="category_id"
                    name="category_id"
                    type="textarea"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setProduct({ ...product, category: { categoryId: e.target.value } })
                    }}
                />
            </FormGroup>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

in onChange function call a separate function and pass the value as parameter

```
onChange={(e)=>sendData(e.target.value)}
```

and

```
let products = {}
const sendData = (value)=>{
setInputValue(value)
productDetails = { ...products, catId:inputValue}
setProd(products)
}
```